# Chebyshev's inequality for complex random variable

Tags: probability, complex-numbers, random-variables, expected-value

Let $Z = X + Y i$ be a complex random variable, where $X, Y$ are real-valued r.v.'s

Denote by $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ and $\sigma^2 = Var[Z]$ the expectation and variance of $Z$.

By Chebyshev's inequality,

$$P(|Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq \sigma k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

If $\mathbb{E}[|Z|] \geq 2 \sigma k$, is it true that

$$P(|Z| \leq \sigma k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2} ? $$

> Why am I asking this?
> If $Z$ was a real-valued r.v. and $E[Z] \geq 2 \sigma k $ then
> $P(Z \leq \sigma k) = P(Z \leq 2\sigma k - \sigma k) \leq P(Z \leq \mathbb{E}[Z] - \sigma k) \leq \underbrace{P(|Z - \mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq   \sigma k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}}_{Chebyshev}$.
> For my question above, we cannot do exactly the same, as $| \ \cdot \ | $ doesn't have the same meaning in the complex numbers...
> I think the answer to my question should be yes! but I'm missing something... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a detour to recap:** the proof of Chebyshev's inequality is just using Markov's inequality on $X^2$, for
$X := |Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]|^2$.

$X$ is a non-negative, *real-valued* random variable, so
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ |Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq a \} 
= \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq a^2 \} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a^2}
= \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq a^2 \} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]|^2]}{a^2}
= \frac{\mathrm{Var}[Z]}{a^2} \tag{1}
$$
still holds.

So we still have Chebyshev's inequality, as you had stated. *(Just for the sake of it, it's worth restating.)*

**Now, for the second (main) part:** *the modulus does satisfy the triangle inequality*, which is what we need:
$$
|\mathbb{E}[Z]| - |Z|
\leq ||\mathbb{E}[Z]| - |Z||
\leq |\mathbb{E}[Z]- Z| \tag{2}
$$

If $|\mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq 2a$, then this implies
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ |Z| \leq 2a - a \} &\leq 
\mathbb{P}\{ |Z| \leq |\mathbb{E}[Z]| - a \} = 
\mathbb{P}\{ |\mathbb{E}[Z]| - |Z| \geq a \}\\
&\leq \mathbb{P}\{ |Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq a \}\\
&\leq \frac{\mathrm{Var}[Z]}{a^2} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I agree with what you wrote but I really did mean to assume $\mathbb{E}[|Z|] \geq 2a$ and not $|\mathbb{E}[Z]| \geq 2a$. Can we conclude something based on the first bound?

Comment: @Babado Is that even true when $Z$ is real-valued? I think I can build a counterexample, e.g., $Z$ being $0$ w.p. $1/2$, $1$ w.p. $1/4$, and $-1$ w.p. 1/4. I can check after lunch, but then $\mathbb{E}[|Z|] = 1/2$, $\sigma = 1/\sqrt{2}$, and $\mathbb{P}\{ |Z| \leq \sigma k\} = 1/2$ for all $k\in(0, \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: How is that a counterexample? If $k \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ then $\mathbb{E}[|Z|] \geq 2 \sigma k $.

Comment: @Babado Take $k=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Then $2\sigma k = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{E}[|Z|]$, so your assumption is satisfied. But $$\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}\{|Z| \leq \sigma k\}> \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{k^2}$$ so the conclusion doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: @Babado You're welcome!